# How to get a list of the grouped values in linq groupby?

Tags: linq, group-by

Linq newbie here, struggling with my first `GroupBy` query.

I have a list of objects of type `KeywordInstance` which represents a keyword, and the ID of the database record to which the keyword was applied.

```
Keyword      RecordID
macrophages  1
macrophages  2
cell cycle   3 
map kinase   2
cell cycle   1
```

What I want is a collection of all keywords, with a list of the `RecordIDs` to which each keyword was applied.

```
Keyword     RecordIDs 
macrophages 1, 2
cell cycle  1, 3
map kinase  2
```

I tried using Linq to get it into a new object. I only managed to get the distinct keywords.

var keywords = allWords
.GroupBy(w => w.keyword)
.Select(g => new {keyword = g.Key});

The problem is that I can't seem to get the values of `g` in any way. `g` is of the type `IGrouping<String, KeywordInstance>` and by documentation, it only has the property `Key`, but not even the property `Value`. All the examples I have seen on the Internet for `groupby` just tell me to select `g` itself, but the result of

```
var keywords = allWords
    .GroupBy(w => w.keyword)
    .Select(g => new {keyword = g.Key, RecordIDs = g});
```

is not what I want.

[image: screenshot of result]

Any try to get something out of g fails with the error message `System.Linq.IGropuing<string, UserQuery.KeywordInstance> does not have a definition for [whatever I tried]`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I can imagine that this question is a duplicate, but I must have searched for the wrong keywords, at least the search results I found did not help me.

Comment: I dont see the problem-- you have a key, and all the records belonging to that key? What where you expecting the records of `g` to look like :) ?

Comment: @JensKloster I don't care what the records of g look like. What I need is a data structure which maps the list of integers '{3, 169, 2179, 2188, 2334, 2389, 2496}' to the key 'FACTOR RECEPTOR'. I thought I would use groupby, and obviously used it wrong, getting g out of it instead of what I needed. So the question is, how do I use it right?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think you are close to you solution.

```
var keywords = allWords
    .GroupBy(w => w.keyword)
    .Select(g => new 
           { 
              keyword = g.Key, 
              RecordIDs = g.Select(c => c.ID)
           });
```

Just `Select` the records you need.
The reason you are seeing the *Keyword*-column as well as the *ID*-column, is becuase it's part of `g`

Comment: thank you, I was trying to do it with something like RecordIDs = g.Values.ID and never thought of using a nested query on g.

Comment: This does not seem to work when querying with Entity Framework. I had to do a "where" to select records by each group key.

Answer (score 2):

```
var keywords = allWords.GroupBy(w => w.keyword);

foreach (var itm in keywords)
{
   var list = itm.ToList();  
   //list returns all of the original properties/values objects from allwords.
   //itm.key returns w.keyword
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to get values (but you lose the `Key`) is like the following:

```
var keywords = allWords
    .GroupBy(w => w.keyword)
    .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault());
```

Or a cleaner approach:

```
var keywords = allWords
    .Select(w => w.keyword)
    .Distinct();
```