# Linq Group by multiple conditions produces missing child records

Tags: .net, linq

So i have a list of StudentGrades i want to fetch from the database, and want to group them using linq. My linq query is this

```
var query = GetListQuery().Where(m => m.StudentId == studentId);
var groupedQuery = query.GroupBy(m => new { Year = m.Year, TermTypeId = m.TermTypeId, TermNumber = m.TermNumber, SchoolId = m.Class.SchoolId })
                        .Select(m => new StudentGradeDto
                        {
                            Year = m.Key.Year,
                            TermTypeId = m.Key.TermTypeId,
                            TermNumber = m.Key.TermNumber,
                            SchoolId = m.Key.SchoolId,
                            StudentGrades = m.ToList()
                        });
```

When I retrieve the record, it looks like this

[image]

One group, as seen in the picture. Has 0 StudentGrades, this group is suppose to have 2 StudentGrades.

How can this be? Even if it is my fault, and the linq generates groups based on conditions, how is it possible for a group have 0 child collection? Which makes me think it is linq problem. I suspect it is the problem with the grouping condition **Class.SchoolId**, but if linq can't translate to SQL properly how am i suppose to rely on it in the future to not produce unseen bugs like this. This just doesn't make sense.

I am at this for couple hours now just can't seem to figure it out. Any experts out there with some inputs?

Comment: Which loading do you use ? Lazy or Eager . Can you be sure GetListQuery result getting Student.StudentGrades list ?

Comment: @SercanTimoçin I am using lazy loading .. in the picture above. Only one group is returning 0 StudentGrades, while the other groups are returning the correct number of StudentGrades

Comment: i think it is not group by problem. Code is looking correct..Can you check your mapping configuration or add here

Comment: @SercanTimoçin what do you mean by mapping config? I am using AutoMapper only for saving purposes.

Comment: i mean entity framework object mapping. relation between Student and StudentGrades

Comment: @SercanTimoçin
ToTable("StudentGrade");

HasOptional(m => m.Class).WithMany().HasForeignKey(m => m.ClassId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

But I can pretty much assure you that the mapping should be ok because for normal operations I am retrieving the records and the navigation property correctly. It is only in this particular case with the grouping

Comment: Please add Student mapping it is StudentGrade mapping. There is no relation with Student. Also WithMany shouldnt empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104682/discussion-between-sercan-timocin-and-andyh0316).

Comment: @SercanTimoçin

HasMany(m => m.StudentGrades).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(m => m.StudentId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

 but regardless, I am fetching a list of studentGrades using Where(StudentId = ...) so it shouldnt matter right? Also, can you explain WithMany() empty? 

I think the mappings are ok because when I fetch a list of StudentGrades I am effectively fetching them correctly. It is when I do grouping that the results return missing records.

Comment: HasMany(m => m.StudentGrades).WithRequired(m=>m.Student).HasForeignKey(m => m.StudentId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false); Please look at http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx If it is not working please add  GetListQuery return class

Comment: @SercanTimoçin tried it didnt work.. I have map config on both Student and StudentGrades that references each others.. establishing a one to many relationship. The GetListQuery's class is too big i cant post it. Sorry. Bottom line is, if i do GetListQuery().Where(m => m.StudentId == studentId).ToList(). I will get 43 records. But If i do the grouping of the IQueryable the way I am doing right now, it will return the grouping such that the sum of the numbers of child collections of each group only adds up to 41 records. With a group having 0 children instead of 2. And this is weird.

Comment: please look at this maybe it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812988/how-to-get-a-list-of-the-grouped-values-in-linq-groupby or come to chat

Comment: @SercanTimoçin I am in chat now. Are you here?